# imageio.read with mac

Tags: java, macos, javax.imageio

I am facing very bad problem. I have program which is try to read the image file and I am doing some operation on that. The same code which is running from windows and when I am try to run same code in apple mac mini (os: 10.7) it getting stuck I a have notice that when compiler comming to line  `ImageIO.read(file)` then it is getting stuck (no exception and error)  ang passing correct file and file is not null. Can any one tell what could be the problem?

Comment: The *compiler* is getting stuck? That sounds unlikely. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: private BufferedImage srcIcon;
try{
srcIcon = ImageIO.read(new File(this.iFile));
}catch(Exception e){
   logger.error("could not read file"+this.iFile);
}

when i am running above code in mac through shell environment it is look like stuck and  when i press ctr+c the start some process and close the file

Comment: So it's not the compiler getting stuck, it's your program.  What is the value of `iFile`?

Comment: the above code working from eclips but not from shell enviorment

Comment: the value of iFile is complete file path

Answer (score 3):

The problem probably comes from your VM arguments, it happens when you use `-XstartOnFirstThread`. 
If this argument is on then AWT won't be able to load up and will make the program hang. To solve this you can add `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to tell AWT not to load at all.

Source: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8019496

Comment: Your answer could be improved if you go into details, why this is a problem with the JRE and what the vm argument does to resolve it.